# Bootstrap - Grid ordering with nested columns (Mobile view)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have panels arranged like in picture:

[image]

Is it possible to order them 1,2,3,4,5 on mobile view??

Sample code:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-8">
       [Panel1]
       [Panel4]
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
       [Panel2]
       [Panel3]
       [Panel5]
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep default bootstrap classes, you can duplicate Panel4 like that:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-8">
      [Panel1]
      [Panel4 class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"] // hide on mobile/table using BS built-in classes
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
      [Panel2]
      [Panel3]
      [Panel4 class="hidden-md hidden-lg"] // hide on desktop
      [Panel5]
   </div>
</div>
```

[Plunkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/1WVCIjQg42hRSYRZp1aK/preview)

Comment: That will work, but i have to duplicate panel. It could be problem in some cases. Anyway thx